# Performance specification for handling duplicate keys in a binary search tree

Tags: c++, algorithm, boost, stl

I was going through the book *Introduction to Algorithms* looking for the best ways to handle duplicate keys in a binary search tree.

There are several ways mentioned for this use case:

1. Keep a boolean flag `x:b` at node `x`, and set `x` to either `x:left` or `x:right` based on the value of `x:b`, which alternates between `FALSE` and `TRUE` each time we
   visit `x` while inserting a node with the same key as `x`.
2. Keep a list of nodes with equal keys at `x`, and insert ´ into the list.
3. Randomly set `x` to either `x:left` or `x:right`.

I understand each implementation has it's own performance hits/misses, and `STL` may implement it differently from `Boost Containers`.

Is the performance bound mentioned in `C++11` specification for the worst time performance of handling duplicate keys , say for `multimap`?

Comment: FWIW, I'm a fan of option 2 - although it might require an additional pointer per node, it clearly illustrates your intent to others who might be inspecting/maintaining your code.

Comment: ya,even i would prefer that, but it would then be linear in time, and as you mentioned, would induce some space overhead too.

Comment: If you do it for fun then there are no difference. If you care about performance then the "unordered", "intrusive" and "flat" versions of multimaps and multisets often beat the binary tree based ones.

Comment: @basav Keeping a list would not increase the time complexity, since by definition you never need to scan through the list for a single particular item.

Comment: got it.since all the values map to the same key, need not be included in time complexity..

Answer (score 0):

In terms of insertion/deletion time 2 is always better because it wouldn't increase the size of the tree and wouldn't require elaborate structure changes when you insert or delete a duplicate.

Option 3 is space optimal if there are small number of duplicates.

Option 1 will require storing 1 extra bit of information (which, in most implementation takes 2 bytes), but the height of the tree will be optimal as compared to 1.

TL;DR: Implementing 2 is slightly difficult, but worthwhile if number of duplicates is large. Otherwise use 3. I wouldn't use 1.